# 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs... error in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

After updating flutter version from 3.13.9. to 3.16.0. this error is shown. Do not know how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use this code in **android/app/build.gradle**

```
android{
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
  }
}
```

Comment: this solved the issue for me!